# Css :focus is not working in mobile and google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

```
input[type='text']#quantity:focus+input,
input[type='text']#quantity+input:focus{
   display: block !important;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 50px;
 }
```

i used this code. It works in firefox. But chrome doesnt. When i focused in #quantity next input is displayed but if I click it changes to display:none.

Comment: could you also share the relevant markup? Are your inputs wrapped in a common container?

Comment: Can you paste your HTML code?

Comment: `<input type="text" value="1" id="quantity">`
      `<input type="number" value="2">`